# How do I fake a ResultExecutionDelegate to unit test an IAsyncResultFilter

Tags: unit-testing, xunit, .net-5, xunit.net

When testing my `IAsyncResultFilter` I know how to create the `ResultExecutingContext` for `OnResultExecutionAsync` but I don't know what I'm supposed to do to create the `ResultExecutionDelegate` parameter.

```cs
public class JsonPrefixFilter : IAsyncResultFilter
{
    public async Task OnResultExecutionAsync(ResultExecutingContext context, ResultExecutionDelegate next)
```

I tried to specify my delegate like so:

```cs
ResultExecutionDelegate next = () => {
    var response = executed.HttpContext.Response;
    response.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

    response.Body.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{}"));
    return Task.FromResult(executed);
};
```

When the filter runs though, after `await next();` is called, the response doesn't have the content type or body I specified.

Comment: Replace the body with your own memory stream. The default context response has an empty stream wrapper

Comment: I assume you are using `DefaultHttpContext` when creating your stub contexts

Comment: I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/grosch-intl/53ad73f7eb09d71462432ba7e6550eb4) which shows both the test class as well as the filter being tested. I am using the `DefaultHttpContext`, yes.

Comment: Based on those helper methods you are using separate HttpContexts instances. You need to be using the same HttpContext for the scope of that test case

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of the delegate using delegate syntax and pass it to the invocation of the subject under test like any other variable.

```csharp
//Arrange
HttpContext http = new DefaultHttpContext();

ResultExecutingContext executing = CreateResultExecutingContext(http); //local
ResultExecutedContext executed = CreateResultExecutedContext(http); //local

ResultExecutionDelegate next = () => {

    //... do something

    var response = executed.HttpContext.Response;
    response.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
    response.Body = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{}"));
    return Task.FromResult(executed);
};

var filter = new JsonPrefixFilter();

//...

//Act
await filter.OnResultExecutionAsync(executing, next);

//Assert
//...
```

Where the helper methods are defined as

```csharp
private static ActionContext CreateActionContext(HttpContext context) => new(context, new(), new());

private static ResultExecutedContext CreateResultExecutedContext(HttpContext context) => 
    new ResultExecutedContext(CreateActionContext(context), Array.Empty<IFilterMetadata>(), new NoOpResult(), new());

private static ResultExecutingContext CreateResultExecutingContext(HttpContext context) => 
    new ResultExecutingContext(CreateActionContext(context), Array.Empty<IFilterMetadata>(), new NoOpResult(), new object());
```

Comment: Thanks, @NKosi.  I updated my question to show the delegate I'm trying to use. Still doing something wrong.

Comment: it gets through the filter now but when I assert against `executed.HttpContext.Response.Body` it's just a `NullStream`

Comment: @Gargoyle and that is with my latest update?